# Apache Mod_Rewrite: include dynamic rewrites with date based variable

Tags: php, json, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

There are some api calls in my app that I want to rewrite to static `.json` files (cache).

My site is for music events and the api calls I want to rewrite to cache are those for the **next 7 days**, so 7 urls to redirect.

So the urls will look like this:

```
api.domain.com/?date=2013-12-01 -> cache_2013_12_01.json
api.domain.com/?date=2013-12-02 -> cache_2013_12_02.json
api.domain.com/?date=2013-12-03 -> cache_2013_12_03.json
api.domain.com/?date=2013-12-04 -> cache_2013_12_04.json
api.domain.com/?date=2013-12-05 -> cache_2013_12_05.json
api.domain.com/?date=2013-12-06 -> cache_2013_12_06.json
api.domain.com/?date=2013-12-07 -> cache_2013_12_07.json
```

But I would not like to redirect any later dates

```
api.domain.com/?date=2013-12-08 -> doesn't redirect
```

Is there a way I can create these redirects without rewriting my .htaccess file with php every day?

Thanks

Comment: Is it always 7 days from today's date?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think .htaccess can do that. but rewriting .htaccess with php is a little dangerous.

I think you can just create a json file folder, e.g.jsondir, and make php re-fill this folder every day with only 7 files. and add this to the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^api.domain.com$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} date=(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})
RewriteRule ^$  jsondir/cache_%1_%2_%3.json [L]
```

Comment: Thanks andrew but this is just a normal redirect, what happends when a date 10 days in the future is requested and there's no file in the cache?

Comment: my point is making php write .htaccess is not a good idea. Or you can use php to send the file, but apache itself might serve the static files better.

Comment: Ok Andrew, I do appreciate your input but maybe use comments for things like this rather than 'answering'. Your answer is generally just re-explaining my question rather than answering it... It generally stops other people from looking at the question if it has an answer...

Comment: But I think I do answer the question:  "is there a way I can create these redirects without rewriting my .htaccess file with php every day". My way not rewriting my .htaccess, but re-fill the file folder.

Answer (score 0):

The best I've been able to come up with is to check if the cached file exists:
I'd still like to be able to create a condition that only matches the next seven days as it seems a bit wasteful to be checking if a file exists for a cache day 8 weeks in the future when the cache only goes forwards 8 days...

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^api.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^date=(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/%1.json -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/%1.json -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ cache/%1.json [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, I think Andrew's approach is essentially correct, that'd be the good way to go about it, and you're rather wrong to fault him for trying to show you alternate approaches. Also, this will be a bit of a smartass answer, in that the method I'll outline is not really preferable, just interesting. But I like to evangelize that mod_rewrite is actually a Turing-complete language, capable to much more than people give it credit for.

Anyhow. The real question is: can mod_rewrite work with dates? It very well can: Apache exposes info about the current time and date through several environmental variables: `%{TIME}`, `%{TIME_DAY}`, `%{TIME_MON}` and `%{TIME_YEAR}` can all be worked into RewriteConds to achieve [neat effects](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/advanced.html#time-dependent). We could, for example, serve only files from the past years:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} date=(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})
RewriteCond %{TIME_YEAR} < %4
```

Unfortunately, mod_rewrite offers no way to do arithmetic (we could, actually, do arithmetic with mod_rewrite alone. We could, but we wouldn't want to!), so we seem to be stuck here.

However, mod_rewrite has a nice mechanism for extending the language: through the use of [RewriteMap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html#prg), we can actually define external rewriting programs we can use as functions in rewrites. Writing a "subtract seven days from the current date" program would be trivial, so we could say

```
RewriteMap sub7day prg:subtract_7_days.py

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} date=(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})
RewriteCond ${sub7days:%1} -lt %{TIME}
```

In short: it's perfectly possible using RewriteMap (utilizing the expressive power of a server-side language), even feasible.

That said, I'd personally do it in PHP, like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} date=(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})
RewriteRule .* cache_serve.php?date=%0
```

Then I could work out the logic in PHP, which is a lot less frustrating than working with mod_rewrite, and a lot less error-prone.